# Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:

Tags: java

Just getting into java, absolute beginner. Using netbeans IDE8.1

Here's a simple program I typed verbatim from a text, which built 'ok':

```
package volume2;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Volume2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    final double BOTTLE_VOLUME = 2;
    final double LITER_PER_OUNCE = 0.0296;
    final double CAN_VOLUME = 12 * LITER_PER_OUNCE;

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of bottles: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bottles = in.nextInt(0);

    double totalVolume = bottles * BOTTLE_VOLUME;

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of cans: ");
    int cans = in.nextInt(0);

    double additionalVolume = cans * CAN_VOLUME;

    totalVolume = totalVolume + additionalVolume;

    System.out.print("Total volume: ");
    System.out.println(totalVolume);

    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

}

However, here's the output:

run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Unclosed character class near index 525 (etc...)
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ^    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2548)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
>       etc....

(I know I'm not formatting the run text and probably the code correctly, so if there's any links on how to that correctly step-by-step on these forums, let me know. The "How do I post..." doesn't specify how to post run output).

Comment: Have you tried compiling with nothing in the main class at all?  This error sounds like it has to do with your setup.  including the full stack trace would help.

Comment: Beside the full stack trace, also post what you are entering at the prompt.

Comment: The full stack trace, meaning the entire run output? I tried to post it here as a response, but too many characters. Actually, it turns out the program didn't build ok, and I can't enter any input.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Method `nextInt()` is an overloaded method, one form taking no arguments, and one form taking an integer argument that is the radix of the number that is being read. You're using the latter in your code and supplying it with a radix value of 0, which is invalid. I'm assuming that you're inputting numbers in base 10, so you might as well use the no arguments form.

```
    int bottles = in.nextInt();
    ...
    int cans = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: sweet, have fun with your calculations :)